# How do I change sounds on Minecraft 1.7.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to know really bad what the sounds are in now in Minecraft 1.7.5 and I cannot find them anywhere! I have tried looking for the right folder and the folder is not there! The folder I am looking for is the resource folder. I looked in all the files of it and still can't find it!

Comment: Where are you looking?  If it's not in appdata you're likely looking in the wrong place.

Comment: This may be a duplicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237690/how-to-add-custom-sounds-in-a-resource-pack/237721#237721

Comment: Casting close vote per @KenzoEngineer's comment (after resolving a duplicate chain). Not 100% convinced this is a duplicate, but the review queue should have a chance to resolve the suggestion.

Comment: @pppery Not sure I’d say it’s a duplicate, but I think it needs more clarity. A question is implied, but not clearly stated. Plus we don’t know where he has looked.

Answer (score 6):

Finding the default in-game sound effects is quite technical. If all you want to do is create a resource pack with sounds, skip down to the *Creating a resource pack* section below.

***The locations of the sound files changed in 1.7. The guide below explains how find the files in the latest version. For pre-1.7 versions, use the guide at the bottom of this answer.***

Minecraft stores a list of virtual file mappings in `%appdata%\.minecraft\assets\indexes\<game version>.json`. To find the physical file for the sound you want, you have to search through this file.

The mapping contains the virtual path of each audio file, and the actual file it is located in. For example, if we wanted to find the second villager talking sound, we would want to look for the following in the file:

```
"minecraft/sounds/mob/villager/no2.ogg"
```

Underneath this line, there will be a line that looks something like this:

```
"hash": "c289aa46fcbcfaf21c8080d57953fd45a4939294"
```

The random characters in the second quotation marks are what we want.

To find the actual file, head to the `.minecraft\assets\objects` directory. This folder contains a big list of sub-folders. Find the sub-folder that is named with the first two characters of the has above (i.e the hash for the villager was `c289aa46fcbcfaf21c8080d57953fd45a4939294`, so we want to look for the folder named `c2`).

Inside this folder, there should be a file with the same name as the hash above. This is the sound file. These files are stored as [Ogg Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) files, so to open them in Windows you need to have a capable media player such as [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

To use the file, first **copy** it, and rename **the copied file** to `<previous name>.ogg` (that is, add the `.ogg` extension). You might need to havve file name extensions visible in order for this to work (in Windows 8, click on the View tab, then check 'File name extensions' in the 'Show/hide' group).

Once this is done, you should be able to open the new file in VLC or similar.

**Creating a resource pack:**

To create a resource pack, head over to `%appdata%\.minecraft\resourcepacks\`. In here, create a folder with a name for your resource pack. Inside here, create three things:

1. A folder called `assets`.
2. An image file, saved as `pack.png`, containing a 'logo' for your resource pack.
3. A file called `pack.mcmeta` which should contain the following:

   ```
   {
      "pack": {
           "pack_format": 1,
           "description": "<a description here>"
       }
   }
   ```

In the `assets` folder, create another folder called `minecraft`. This is where all of your stuff goes.

Now, take a look back in `%appdata%\.minecraft\assets\indexes\<game version>.json`. If you want to change any sounds, you should first find the virtual path of the sound in question in this file, and then the folders and file in your resource pack look like the structure set out in there. For example, if you wanted to change the piston 'in' sound, you would create a folder called `sounds`, then another called `tile`, then another folder called `piston`, and finally, you would save your new sound as `in.ogg`.

**Remember that all sound files must be saved as [Ogg Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) files. You can convert sound files to this format with free programs such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).**

**Finding the default sound files for pre-1.7:**

The default sounds and music for Minecraft 1.7 on Windows can be found in `%appdata%\.minecraft\assets\virtual\legacy`, sorted into folders and files. If this directory is not empty, you can also use it as a reference for the structure of your resource pack.