# How to add custom sounds in a resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing Minecraft for over 2 years, and I wanted to get into making resource packs. I understand how to change textures, but I wanted to change the sounds. I know how to access the 1.8 sound files, and was wondering if there is an easier way to change the sounds in 1.8. I have been using: *.minecraft/assets/indexes/1.8.json* and then going to: *.minecraft/assets/objects/##* to change the sounds.

Comment: @Texenox While I approve your edit, I'm wondering if the use of "texture pack" versus "resource pack" is not symptomatic of the issue at hand. OP are you aware that resource packs can replace sounds just as easily as textures since 1.6(?) (hence the re-naming to resource pack)?

Comment: @MrLemon The asker is essentially referring to exactly that. If they were referring to the old texture packs, would they be asking how to change the sounds through one?

Comment: What is the current way you are changing the sounds? Can't really offer an "easier way" without knowing what you are currently doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add sounds to a resource pack, not replace them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361803/add-sounds-to-a-resource-pack-not-replace-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suggest changing Minecraft sounds by going into the game files so you should make a resource pack. If you don't want to change any textures, then you just have to make a sounds folder.

Asumming you know that you know about the pack.mcmeta and pack.png, you just have to make a file directory like this:

```
my_custom_resource_pack/assets/minecraft/sounds/[category]
```

For example, I want to change the villager item sound to me say "eyo". First, I would use a program to record me saying ey and I would save it as .ogg. use this link: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/mapping-and-modding-tutorials/1571574-all-minecraft-playsound-file-names to see what to name it to. In my case it would be `mob.villager.idle1.ogg`. You can see that the prefix is `mob`, meaning that the "category" folder we made earlier should be renamed to mob. After this, you should be done!

Put that folder into your resource packs folder and have fun!