# How do I create a resource pack with sounds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've already looked at [How to add custom sounds in a resource pack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237690/how-to-add-custom-sounds-in-a-resource-pack) and it didn't work for me. I created `sound_pack/assets/minecraft/sounds/mob/mob.horse.death.ogg` with the `pack.mcmeta` as

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 2,
    "description": "Mod With Sounds"
  }
}
```

And I made a `pack.png` file with an appropriately sized png file. I loaded my game, turned on the texture pack (`1.8`) and killed a horse. Everything was as normal Minecraft! Why??!

P.S. I am also aware of [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/mapping-and-modding-tutorials/1571574-all-minecraft-playsound-file-names).

Update: I changed it to be `sound_pack/assets/minecraft/sounds/mob/horse/death.ogg` like i believe it's supposed to be, but when I killed a horse, my game froze permanantally. Strange...

Comment: Please, if you're going to downvote my question, please tell me why you did so. Thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why someone downvoted, but it may have been because they know that gamedev questions are off-topic and hence texture pack creation is borderline. I personally upvoted you since your question was well-written, but I'm not sure whether it is on-topic or not.